# JavaFX - Deselect text in TextField when open new stage

Tags: java, javafx

I have designed a simple form with a TextField and a Button.

When the stage is created, with the scene containing the form, the TextField must be preloaded with a character. The problem is that, when the form shows up, the character is selected, as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlNv1.png).

I tried textfield.deselect() or textfield.positionCaret(1) (or both) but nothing has changed.
I don't want to remove the focus on the textfield, but deselect the text and move the caret at the end (so that if the user write something, the first character will not be overwritten).

This is the code I wrote:

```
try {
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/resources/view/quick-search.fxml").openStream());
        QuickSearchCtrl quickSearchCtrl = (QuickSearchCtrl) loader.getController();
        quickSearchCtrl.text_tf.setText(text);
        quickSearchCtrl.text_tf.deselect();
        primaryStage.setTitle("");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 230, 54));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can instantiate a TextField without any text in it in JavaFX or just a blank string, and if not you could just delete the text immediately after loading the scene.

Comment: Have you tried doing some of the stuff you tried after `primaryStage.show();`?

Comment: @Sedrick yes, but problem not solved. 
For those who are wondering why I need this: it's a customer request. Example to better understand: you select a cell (of any row) corresponding to the "Firstname" column and type "jack". It automatically sort the table with Firstname in ascending order, show you the window with the word "jack" in the TextField, and select the first row with "jack" or "Jack" as Firstname. So the "j" of "jack" must both open the search window and be inserted in the TextField.
I hope I have clarified. Sorry for any grammatical errors, I'm not native English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an evil crutch, but this work.

```
quickSearchCtrl.text_tf.setText(text);
deselect(quickSearchCtrl.text_tf);
```

---

```
private void deselect(TextField textField) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        if (textField.getText().length() > 0 &&
                textField.selectionProperty().get().getEnd() == 0) {
            deselect(textField);
        }else{
            textField.selectEnd();
            textField.deselect();
        }
    });
}
```